# Change python2 to python3 when using the terminal for jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I hope someone can help me out with the following;

On my mac I have by default Python 2.x. I now have to open Jupyter notebook with Python 3.8 from the terminal. I have already downloaded Python 3.8. I tried `python3 -m notebook` but this doesn’t seem to work. Does someone know how to do this?

To download pip I used in my terminal:

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
```

Using the terminal I installed the package

```
$ pip install rdflib
```

then I installed Jupyter notebook in my terminal using:

```
$ pip install jupyterlab
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi YYY, welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you install Jupyter? If so, how did you do it?

Comment: What is the output in your terminal after you run `python3 -m notebook`?

Comment: @David Z I used: $ pip install jupyterlab in my terminal and before that I already installed pip.

Comment: every Python uses own modules - you have to install it with `pip3 install ...` or `python3 -m pip install ...`

Comment: @YYY Thanks, could you edit that information into your question?

Comment: @Mr.C I get this as output: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3: No module named notebook

Comment: @DavidZ Yes, ofc!

Comment: @furas when I type in $pip3 --version pip  I get:                                                      20.1.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8). Doesn't this mean pip for python 3.8 is already installed?

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting in your post but I'm not sure I got it right. Could you check it and fix it, please? Also, I'd highly encourage you to edit the information from your last comment into the question as well. That'd be very useful to include.

Comment: @YYY **pip3** is installed, but you need to install Jupyter *for Python3* using pip3.

Comment: `pip3 --version` shows `(python 3.8)` so it is installed and works with Python 3.8 and you have to use `pip3` instead of `pip` to install module `notebook/jupyter` for `Python 3.8`. Using `pip` you can install modules for Python 2.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Python 2 is the default on your system, it's likely (but not certain) that `pip` runs the Python 2 version of Pip. You can check by running

```
$ pip --version
```

It will print out the Python version that `pip` works with. If you find that it is Python 2, that means that running `pip install` to install a package only installs it for Python 2.

In order to make the package available in your default version of Python 3, you'd have to run

```
pip3 install notebook
```

I'd guess that for you, the default version of Python 3 is probably Python 3.8, unless you have yet *another* version of Python 3 installed. If you do, then you might need to run

```
pip3.8 install notebook
```

to be completely sure that it gets installed with Python 3.8 rather than whatever other version you have installed.